# How to derive decimal notation of $2n$ from the notation of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a number with decimal notation as this: $a_{k}a_{k-1}\dots a_{1}$.

It is very obvious that
$n=10^ka_k+10^{k-1}a_{k-1}+\dots+a_1$

My question is, how to derive the decimal notation for $2n$? I think this is somehow related to field theory but I just don't have any idea...Can someone help me?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "derive"? Are you asking if there is a "closed form" vs. the grade school "long-hand" radix multiplication algorithm? If the former, what sort of  closed forms do you permit?

Comment: Is the use of "$n$" for both *the number* as well as *the number of digits* intentional? (BTW, a number with $n$ digits only reaches the $10^{n-1}$s place.)

Comment: Ok, I notice the mistake I made. Now my question is: How to express $2n$'s decimal notation with $a_{k}$,...,$a_{1}$? I need the answer for a number theory problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a couple of examples might help:

Let $n=a_1$.
Then $2n= \left\{ \matrix{\phantom{0000000}(2a_1), \quad a_1<5\\(1)(2a_1-10), \quad a_1\ge5} \right.$

Let $n=a_2a_1$.

Then $2n= \left\{ \matrix{\phantom{0000000000}(2a_2)(2a_1), \quad a_1<5,a_2<5\\\phantom{00}(2a_2+1)(2a_1-10), \quad a_1\ge5,a_2<5\\
\phantom{000}(1)(2a_2-10)(2a_1),\quad a_1<5,a_2\ge 5\\(1)(2a_2-9)(2a_1-10),\quad a_1\ge5,a_2\ge5} \right.$

In general, the $j^\text{th}$digit $b_j$ of $2n$, when $n=a_p a_{p-1}\cdots a_1$
will either be

$(2a_j) \mod{10},$

$(2a_j+1) \mod{10},$

or $1$.

We now have the result $\cdots$

$$b_j = \left\{ \matrix{\phantom{00}(2a_j) \mod{10},\quad a_{j-1}<5,\\ (2a+1) \mod{10}, \quad \text{otherwise}. } \right.$$

Comment: I guess $1$ also fits into the pattern with $a_{p+1}=0.$ So, depending on the previous digit, there are two possibilities.

Comment: I think this is a good answer but it is still unable to solve the problem I am facing...

Comment: If it's a good answer to the question you **asked**, then you should accept it, and perhaps should ask another question closer to the problem that you actually want to solve. It may well turn out that there's some approach to that problem that may surprise you (and not involve this particular kind of computation).

Comment: @Mr.Infinity Note that the above answer is nothing but the grade-school radix multiplication algorithm specialized to a single digit multiplier. Hence my initial comment on the question - intended to spark clarification of *precisely* what you seek - which still is not clear.

Comment: @JohnHughes It's not a good idea to rush questioners to accept answers to questions when the question remains unclear. Nor is it a good idea to answer them.

Comment: @Mr.Infinity *"I think this is a good answer but it is still unable to solve the problem I am facing..."* ... then maybe you should've asked about the problem directly if that is what you care about? And not ask about "decimal notation of $2n$" without providing context, when you care about the context.